# Beautifulsoup of href

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Can someone please advise how do i retrieve href and img values from `<td>` . I have written the following piece of code to retrieve the result as given below. I am able to retrieve the value till `<td>`. I'm not sure how to retrienve further.

Please note there are a lot of `<tr>`values . I have just given two as an example.

MyCode:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url="http://mywebsite.com/"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

records = [] 
tabledata = soup.find("table", {"class" : "class1"})
for row in tabledata.findAll('tr'):
    col = row.findAll('td')
    if col:
        col1 = col[1].string.strip()
        col2 = col[2].string.strip()
        col3 = col[3].string.strip()
        record = '%s %s %s' % (col1,col2,col3)
        records.append(record)


for values in records:
    print values
```

data

```
<table class="class1">
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Heading1</th>
<th>Heading2</th>
<th>Heading3</th>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://image.com/new.png"/></td>
<td>Data1</td>
<td><a href="www.sample.com">Data2</a></td>
<td>Data3</td>
</tr>
```

Output:

```
Data1 Data2 Data3
```

Required Output:

```
Data1 Data2 Data3 www.sample.com new.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
#url="http://mywebsite.com/"
#page=urllib2.urlopen(url)


def getdata(col):
    record = []
    for image in col.findAll('img'):
        src = image.get('src')
        record.append(src)
    for a in col.findAll('a'):
        href = a.get('href')
        record.append(href)
    if col.string:
        record.append(col.string.strip())
    return record


def extract():
    url="test.html"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(url).read())

    records = [] 
    tabledata = soup.find("table", {"class" : "class1"})
    for row in tabledata.findAll('tr'):
        cols = row.findAll('td')
        for col in cols:
            record = getdata(col)
            records.extend(record)
    return records

if __name__ == "__main__":
    records = extract()
    print "recorsd:", records
    for v in records:
        print v
```

output:

```
http://image.com/new.png
Data1
www.sample.com
Data2
Data3
```

Loop through all the 'td', extract necessary data and append to records.

Answer (score 0):

The string property will only return the text content of the child nodes most likely. You will also need to look for the other tags you are interested in ( and ) from each col and extract the properties from those you want to print out.